# Bluestacks App Player graphics driver error on Intel desktop board D945GCLF

Tags: windows-8, drivers, bluestacks

I am trying to install Bluestacks App Player on a machine running Windows 8 Pro 32bit. But whenever I do install the application it shows this error that `Please install Graphics driver`.

Below are the machine details:

- Motherboard: Intel® desktop board D945GCLF
- Operating system: Windows 8 Pro 32Bit (x86)

Officially there are no drivers available for Windows 8, so I installed the Windows 7 32bit drivers.

But still after that I'm unable to run BlueStacks and the same error being produced.

I found the drivers at [this URL](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Desktop+Boards&ProductLine=Intel%C2%AE+945+Express+Chipset+Family+Boards&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE+Desktop+Board+D945GCLF)

Help me how to solve this issue.

Comment: Sounds like you might be out of luck.  If the Windows 7 drivers don't statisfy the player there isn't much you can do as a user of said player.

Comment: any error codes?with it normally bluestacks would generate popups with error codes

Comment: Check your `dxdiag` to see if everything looks to be in order?

Answer (score 0):

There might be two Scenarios where graphic card is identified by an software, Blue stacks uses two things

```
1.Microsoft’s proprietary Direct3D >>used to run windows

2.OpenGL >>used to Run android Programs
```

Retry by updating your graphic card drivers

From [msdn](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-hardware/latest-graphics-driver-update-makes-bluestacks/1f67d99f-3626-4110-aa22-773856b226cb) Forums :

```
Method 1: I would suggest you to roll back to the previous driver.



a)      Press Windows key + X on the keyboard.

b)      Click Device Manager.

c)       Double-click on Display Adapters.

d)      Double-click on your Graphic Card Drivers

e)      Select the Driver Tab

f)       Click on Roll Back Driver.



Method 2: I would suggest you to uninstall and reinstall the graphic drivers and check.



a)      Click on Start, type Device Manager and hit enter.

b)      Go to display adapter.

c)       Right click on the video card, click on uninstalls.



Reboot the computer to update the driver’s automatically.



In case not able to update the drive I would suggest you to manually download and install the drivers

from the Manufacturer’s website and check.





Follow the steps to install it in compatibility mode;



a)      Press the ‘Windows key + W’ key on the keyboard.

b)      Type compatibility in the search box and then press Enter.

c)       Click “Run programs made for previous versions of Windows” option from the list appeared in the left side.

d)      Select the drivers or games and install.



Make older programs compatible with this version of Windows



Most programs created for earlier versions of Windows also work in this version of Windows, but some older programs might run poorly or not at all. If a program written for an earlier version of Windows doesn't work correctly, you can try changing the compatibility settings for the program, either by using the Program Compatibility Troubleshooter or manually choosing compatibility settings.



http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/older-programs-compatible-version-windows



What is program compatibility?



http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/what-program-compatibility



Method 3: Try installing the application in Clean Boot and check.



Perform Clean Boot.



To help troubleshoot error messages and other issues, you can start Windows 8 by using a minimal set of drivers and startup programs. This kind of startup is known as a "clean boot." A clean boot helps eliminate software conflicts.



Please refer to the link and follow the steps and check.



http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135



Please refer to the section “How to determine what is causing the problem by performing a clean boot”



Important: Reset the computer to start to normal startup.

Note: After you have finished troubleshooting, follow these steps to boot to normal startup.

a)      Press the ‘Windows + R’ key on the keyboard.

b)      In the ‘Run’ window type ’MSCONFIG’ and click ‘Ok’.

c)       On the ‘General’ tab, click the ‘Normal Startup’ option, and then click ‘OK’.

d)      When you are prompted to restart the computer, click ‘Restart’.



After you determine the startup item or the service that causes the problem, contact the program manufacturer to determine whether the problem can be resolved.
```

Normally updating gpu will solve problems,if you have installed directx update it too,

Update Graphics Driver For [Intel Chipset](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect) from here

once you post the error code it would help us to explore further